# HTML / CSS : Display flex on logo not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

hope you all are doing well.

I am new to web development and I am coding along with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFvfqUMjvsA&ab_channel=CodingLab and around 5:20 timestamp I am not getting the same result as the one in the video. Can anyone please help me understand what's wrong?

Edit: I tried changing to `display: inline-flex;` but I'm still not getting the same result.

Expected Result based on video:

[image: Expected Result based on video]

Actual Result I am getting:

[image: Actual Result I am getting]

```css
.sidebar header .image-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidebar">
  <header>
    <!-- ===== Logo ===== -->
    <div class="image-text">
      <span class="image">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100jpg" alt="candlestick logo">
                </span>
    </div>

    <!-- ===== Logo Text ===== -->
    <div class="text header-text">
      <span class="name">TradeJournal</span>
      <span class="creator">By RS</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, to make the code work you need that

**1.** the image **2.** span (text)

to be inside the same parent element 
so in his case, it would be `.image-text` but in your case is the `<header>`

> you may think: *"but I write the same CSS, why is not working?"*

so yes, the problem is not in your CSS! instead is in HTML!

❌ your previous HTML code:

```html
<nav>
 <header>
   <div class="image-text">
     <!-- image tags code -->
   </div>

   <!-- text (error: you putted this outside the .image-text) -->
  </header>
</nav>
```

✅ the code needs to be like this:

```html
<header>
  <div class="image-text">
    <!-- image tags code -->
    <!-- text -->
  </div>
</header>
```

the CSS don't touch it, is ok!

> good learning!

Comment: Thanks!! but may I know the reason why '.image-text' is removed? On the video it seems like it is working.

Comment: @RenAdrian 5 minutes, I will see the video

Comment: @RenAdrian yes, I know. I will update the answer

Comment: @RenAdrian corrected with the new answer, see if solved your problem (the problem was in html)

Comment: Aha, I know my mistake now. Thanks so much @Laaouatni

Answer (score 0):

Add flex in Header

```
.sidebar header {
display: flex;
align-items: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are to set the flex on the parent element not child

```
.sidebar header{
display: flex;
align-items: center; }
```

Comment: Thanks!! but may I know the reason why '.image-text' is removed? On the video it seems like it is working.

Comment: May be u didn't arrange the HTML well..

Comment: Changing the position of parent and child in the Html will make the Css not to work

Comment: Adding Flex is like Floating the element Next to Each other

Comment: You can add **flex-wrap to wrap**   to make them more close to eachother

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidebar header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidebar">
  <header>
    <!-- ===== Logo ===== -->
    <div class="image-text">
      <span class="image">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100jpg" alt="candlestick logo">
                </span>
    </div>

    <!-- ===== Logo Text ===== -->
    <div class="text header-text">
      <span class="name">TradeJournal</span>
      <span class="creator">By RS</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</nav>
```